# refresh page once checkbox is checked (in the background)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

How can I refresh the page (in the background, seamlessly) when a user checks a checkbox so that once the checkbox is checked off, that div or task is then moved to another location because it's completed?

I have separated them like so

```
  def home
    if current_user
        @todos = current_user.todos.where(completed: false)
    end
  end

  def complete
    if current_user
        @todos = current_user.todos.where(completed: !false)
    end
  end
```

So that once the checkbox is checked it is moved, and this works - but the page has to be refreshed to see that the task has been moved.

In my todos controller where I mark the task complete it looks like this

```
  def completed
    if @todo.update_attribute(:completed, !@todo.completed)
      flash[:success] = "Congratulations, it was successful."
      redirect_to dashboard_path
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "ERROR: Please try again."
      render :new
    end
  end
```

And my view is as so

```
<% @todos.each do |todo| %>
    <div class="card hoverable">
        <div class ="card-content mh-100">
            <span class="card-title"><%= todo.title %></span>
            <p><%= todo.item %></p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action grey lighten-5">
            <p style="margin: 0;">
            <%= check_box_tag 'todo[completed]', todo.id, todo.completed, data: { remote: true, url: url_for(controller: :todos, action: :completed, id: todo), method: "POST" }, id: todo.id, :onclick => "Materialize.toast('Todo Completed, Grats!', 4000)" %>
            <%= label_tag todo.id, "COMPLETE", :class => 'strikethrough' %>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

But how can I refresh the page, or the div when the checkbox is checked so the task disappears seamlessly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your div a unique ID based on the todo id value so that you can select it for removal:

```
<div class="card hoverable" id="todo_container_<%= todo.id %>">
```

Add a class to your check box so that you can specify a click handler:

```
check_box_tag 'todo[completed]', todo.id, todo.completed, class: 'todo_completed', data: { remote: true, url: url_for(controller: :todos, action: :completed, id: todo), method: "POST" }, id: todo.id, :onclick => "Materialize.toast('Todo Completed, Grats!', 4000)"
```

Then (assuming you are using jQuery) specify the click handler:

```
$(".todo_completed").click(function(){
  // it looks like you've got all the info you need for your ajax call in the data attributes attached to the checkbox, so I think the call just looks like this:
  $.ajax($(this).data());
});
```

Finally your controller needs to render a .js template instead of redirecting - just call it completed.js.erb and it should be rendered automatically. In that template put the javascript to remove the container div from the DOM:

```
// completed.js.erb
$("todo_container_<%= @todo.id %>").remove();
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, I have one question, I'm getting this `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `todo' for #<#<Class:0x007f283e1ff370>:0x007f2834b11968>):
    1: $("todo_container_<%= todo.id %>").remove();
  app/views/todos/completed.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_todos_completed_js_erb___3190582875541384523_69905408839680'
  app/controllers/todos_controller.rb:70:in `block (2 levels) in completed'
  app/controllers/todos_controller.rb:69:in `completed'` but I'm not sure how to fix it, this is when I click the todo checkbox in my rails console I get this error

Comment: That's a typo - should be `@todo.id`, not `todo.id` - referencing the @todo instance variable. I've updated my answer

Comment: One quick question, so I have rendered a format.js should I also render format.html to do something? Or, is just one enough?

Comment: .js templates are for javascript responses to ajax requests - if your controller action is only ever going to respond to an ajax request, all you need is a .js template. However, there are cases where you might want a controller to be able to respond with .js or to render a full html page. In that case you want both templates.

Comment: Understood, that makes perfect sense -- I thought the HTML would be as a backup perhaps in case JS is disabled for some reason, but I'll leave it as just a .js. Thanks again for your help and detailed answer and explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Use removeChild() with the div id to remove it, just put this in an onClick handler for the checkbox.

If desired:

Save the div when you delete it (from the return value of removeChild) in a variable, so if the checkbox is unchecked, you can use the div in createChild().